# Regular Expression to search for string indicating error message but avoid specific string

Tags: regex, string

I'd like to detect lines with error messages in a log file, but not one specific message.

Example:

```
bla ER2323 text<BR>
bla ER4444 text<BR>
bla Er2323333 text<BR>
bla bla bla
bla ER23 text<BR>
er1111 text<BR>
```

All error messages containing ER+4 digits should be captured, but NOT the ER4444 message.

Regular expression:

```
[Ee][Rr]+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

captures the error messages. How can I avoid the ER4444 message?

Comment: What makes `ER4444` different from `ER2323` ? Btw you current expression can be written as `/ER\d{4}/i`.

Comment: what regexp flavour, what tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead -

```
[Ee][Rr](?!4444)\d{4}
```